# Mongodb giving different count results from count function and aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection in mongodb named users. I am trying to find count of all documents in the collection.

Surprisingly following queries are giving different results. 
For

```
db.users.find({}).count()
```

and

```
`db.users.count()`
```

the output is 533911, and for

```
db.users.aggregate(
    [
        { $group: { _id: "$_id" } },
        { $group: { _id : null, count : { $sum : 1 } } }
    ]
)
```

and

```
db.users.aggregate(
        [
            { $group: { _id : null, count : { $sum : 1 } } }
        ]
    )
```

the output is 533950.

Can anyone tell me why aggregation and normal queries are returning different results ? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see 2 possible reasons :

1. If your collection is sharded, you should use the aggregation framework to count documents because the count operation may be inaccurate due to chunk moves or orphaned documents. [How to count in Sharded Clusters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/#sharded-clusters)
2. If you are using WiredTiger storage engine (which is most likely now as it's the default since V3.2), the statistics stored by WiredTiger can be inaccurate after an unclean shutdown. You should run a `db.collection.validate()` on each collections. [WiredTiger unclean shutdown](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/#accuracy-after-unexpected-shutdown)

Note : You can reduce the "confusion" by removing the orphaned documents with the [cleanupOrphaned](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/cleanupOrphaned/#dbcmd.cleanupOrphaned) command but in a sharded environment you should always use the aggregation framework.

Comment: Yup it worked. We are not using sharded collection. This was the second case where WiredTiger statistics were not accurate. Running validate() on collections worked. Thanks :-)

Comment: For more specific context on the outcome of `count()` versus an aggregation query: as at MongoDB 3.6 a  `count()` without a query filter is a "fast count" (or estimated count) based on collection statistics which are periodically persisted by WiredTiger. The equivalent aggregation query (grouping by `_id`) is more accurate but likely to take longer because it actually counts the matching values.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.users.aggregate(
    [
        { $group: { _id: "$_id" } },
        { $group: { _id : null, count : { $sum : 1 } } }
    ]
)
```

is counting null values also.

```
db.users.count()
```

not counting null values.

Comment: aggregation query is counting _id fields, which cannot be null. Moreover later one is calculating count of documents. In this case, what are you referring to, when talking about not counting null values.

Comment: { $group: { _id : null, count : { $sum : 1 } } } is counting all occurences

Comment: The two aggregation examples in the question are equivalent to each other and the initial `$group` isn't doing anything useful: `_id` values are already unique and `$group` by `_id: null` will accumulate on that basis. The real difference is a fast/estimated `count()` versus one calculated with aggregation.